# asp.net multiline textbox default value

Tags: asp.net, xml, xhtml, textarea

I am having a problem with the asp.net multi line textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Oohrl" 
    runat="server"
    CssClass="textEntry"
    ClientIDMode="Static"
    Text="{/oohru/form/oohrl}">
</asp:TextBox>
```

This works fine with text= when the page loads it puts the appropriate value in there from the XML file

However the following does NOT do that

```
<asp:TextBox id="Description"
    TextMode="MultiLine"
    Columns="50"
    Rows="4"
    runat="server"
    ClientIDMode="Static"
    Text="{/oohru/form/desc}">
</asp:TextBox>
```

it just puts {/oohru/form/desc} as the literal text inside of the textbox.  The multi line box renders as a textarea vs an input in the first example.

Below is how the xhtml is constructed on the browser
This is the one that works, where asdf IS the proper value that it should display

```
<input class="textEntry" 
    id="Oohrl"
    value="asdf" 
    name="ctl00$RightColumn$Oohrl" 
    type="text">
```

This is the one that doesn't

```
<textarea id="Description" 
    cols="50" 
    rows="4" 
    name="ctl00$RightColumn$Description">
    {/oohru/form/desc}
</textarea>
```

I did also try using my own textarea with runat="server" and another without that, it still won't put a value in .  Is there a reason xslt won't render a value into a text area??

Comment: You may be confusing XSLT with ASP.NET.

Comment: No in this case what is happening is I have 2 asp.net pages, the one being loaded is an aspx page that generates XSLTand the other asp.net page generates the XML so the asp.net page here is the XSLT one that's why I need to put the xslt in there as it is going to read the other ASP.NET page [which is XML]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Ajax TextBoxWaterMark Control** to solve this issue. You need not use classes for this.

Comment: You saved my life bro! I've been looking for 3 days why the heck my Gridview was removing the default Text="my text" value at run time. This Ajax is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

- everything which you write in
  double-course for text property, it
  shown as default text for that ,so
  you are getting like that
- see the link below might it will help
  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_xml.asp)